# Angular Page becomes white after adding MatDialog code

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I was trying to use MatDialog to open a dialog with information in it. I followed a tutorial and in the component, I put a button that would call a "openDialog()" method and in the typescript I added the method along with changing the contructor. After changing the constructor, the page became completely blank, not showing a thing.

Here is the typescript with the changed constructor and method. (This is in the same component as the button in the html)

```
export class InfoComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}
  openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(BenefitsPopupComponent);
  } 
  ngOnInit(): void {    
  }
}
```

Here is the basic button html

```
<button (click)="openDialog()">test</button>
```

and here is the component html that it will open

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title> test </h2>
```

the typescript on the component that is being opened is empty

I've tried various tutorials and such but keep getting the same results. I believe it has to do with the constructor but im not entirely sure. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

this is my first time answering a question so I will try my best.

I'm not really sure if you mean that you want the popup to open a seperate component but I would rather do it as follows:

My Appomponent.ts looks like this:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }
  @ViewChild('myDialog', {static: false}) myDialog!: TemplateRef<any>;
  openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(this.myDialog);
  } 
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  doSomeAction() {
    console.log('log something')
    this.dialog.closeAll()
  }
}
```

And then my html code looks like this:

```html
<button (click)="openDialog()">test</button>

<ng-template #myDialog>
    <h2 matDialogTitle>Test</h2>
    <mat-dialog-content>
        <p>Add some text here
        </p>
    </mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-dialog-actions align="end">
        <button mat-button matDialogClose>Cancel</button>
        <button mat-button (click)="doSomeAction()">Do Something</button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
</ng-template>
```

This is just the way I would approach it, not sure if this actually helps you or not.